# Aliens abduct humans to crew a ship and represent Earth in an ongoing war. Humanity doesn't have space faring capabilities

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

The story begins with some mysterious glowing objects falling from the sky, and intrepid humans taking a closer look at said objects. As they approach the object like rock pinch them, some dying and others becoming highly aggressive and very strong.

After a couple of dozen of them are infected they get abducted by a spaceship, formed into groups and forced to fight with batons battle royale style. The winners are taken to a space carrier, and assigned to a small ship crewed by 4 to 6 humans. They discover that the carrier has multiple alien races, each crew representing their planets, and they have insignia that change with rank, first rank is a circle, I cant remember the second one, the third rank is a triangle, the forth is a diamond shape with four sides, the more sides the higher the rank.

At the end of the book after the battle, every crew is return to their planet, the Captain of the human crew tricks the alien alliance and decides to crash his ship on Earth to give a change to humanity to studied it, and the aliens not recovering it because for them is old tech, and not worth the time and effort to recover it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The book is called [*Rebel Fleet*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/31675453-rebel-fleet) and is the the first in a series called [Rebel Fleet by BV Larson](https://www.goodreads.com/series/193930-rebel-fleet).

The protagonist is a soldier that dives off the coast to find a glowing rock that fell from the sky. Only a few survive this I believe, then aliens take them to fight in their navy.

All the aliens are of humanoid descent, but from a different base animal than a monkey, all predators, such as a tiger.

As all the aliens are descendants from predatory animals they prize aggression and martial combat above all else, leading to a Battle-Royal-like test with 'Stun' sticks.

The humans' main advantage in these fights and when piloting spacecraft is that humans come from an animal that is not an apex predator, and are willing to be devious.

Rank in the fleet is based on promotion points that are handed out by officers for combat feats or aggression; these points affect the soldiers' badges that are morphic, changing as needed.

The book ends with the Rebel Fleet disbanding after a large engagement and Leo hiding his ship on Earth, under the guise of a crash so that Humans can reverse engineer the tech.

> They hunt us. They bomb our worlds for target practice.
>
> A star cluster in the constellation of Orion rotates once every thousand years. Those who rule there have an ancient tradition: When each cycle ends, they train their fleets by spilling the blood of lesser beings.
>
> The enemy fleets are coming again. In response, the Rebel Worlds gather their starships to face the terrifying threat, and this time humanity is asked to stand with them.
>
> The last time they considered Earth, Vikings in longboats were raiding English coastlines. Today, we’re less primitive. Today, we're a target.
>
> One man is chosen to command Earth's single ship in the Rebel Fleet. When the war breaks out, Leo Blake must win it… or die trying.

Comment: Rhinos are not predators.